# What happens if a snake comes from the river during Varsi ritual of pitru?

Tags: animals, sraddha, omens

Recently I was doing the ritual of Varsi at Haridhwar on the banks of river Ganga. The  Shivalinga was there, and suddenly a snake appeared from the river and we had to go around it in order to continue the ritual.

Is it considered a bad or good omen?

Comment: I don't think Shiva Lingam is a valid tag here although I left it for you to remove it.

Comment: I removed it, but please provide me some answer as it is really important to me. Thank you dear.